# how grails spring security filter works

Tags: grails, spring-security

I would like to write a filter for a Facebook login, without to use the Facebook plugin. For Facebook authentification, I'll use Spring Social Facebook with annoation configuration.

The problem is who to write a filter.

I tried :

class FacebookAuthFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

```
  public FacebookAuthFilter() {
      super("/j_facebook_security_check")
      println "constructor"
  }

  @Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest arg0,
      HttpServletResponse arg1) throws AuthenticationException,
      IOException, ServletException {
      println "attemptAuthentication"
      return null;
  }
```

}

In Bootstrap.goovy

```
SpringSecurityUtils.registerFilter ('facebookAuthFilter', SecurityFilterPosition.SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER.order + 10)
```

In resources.groovy

```
facebookAuthFilter(FacebookAuthFilter) {
  authenticationManager = ref('authenticationManager')
  rememberMeServices = ref('rememberMeServices')
}
```

At server start, I can see "constructor" in console. But not"attemptAuthentication".

How to enter in attemptAuthentication() ? I would like the map "/auth/facebook" to attemptAuthentication() method.

Thanks

EDIT :

Hi Igor, unfortunately, it's not work.

```
public FacebookAuthFilter() {
    super("/myapp/facebook")
    println "constructor"
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest arg0,
        HttpServletResponse arg1) throws AuthenticationException,
        IOException, ServletException {
    println "attemptAuthentication"
    return null;
}
```

then I go to

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/facebook
```

Blank page and in console :
2014-09-26 18:09:57 [localhost].[/myapp] Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'grails-errorhandler'

Comment: you said you would like to map to `/auth/facebook` but really mapping to `/j_facebook_security_check`. which of them correct?

Comment: it's not works. I don't find a documentation or simple example.

Comment: start with this http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#overall-architecture Or simply use an existing plugin, extending Spring Security with custom auth requires a lot of knowledge of internal stuff of Spring Security, or you could easily get something insecure (and you'll never know about it, until your system got hacked)

Comment: the problem is facebook plugin (http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-facebook) not works with oauth plugin (http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-oauth2-provider). facebook connexion is deactivate. for this I try to write my own facebook connexion.Thank you Igor. Documentation seems good.

Comment: if it have problem with oauth2 please create a issue ticket with details, it's better to fix issue rather that write a clone

Comment: ok I write a post in github for each plugin